# Is this a Doctrine bug ? Requiring a non-existent file

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am following the [Getting Started with Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) tutorial step-by-step,
and I am almost finished with it. But surprisingly, near the end of it I am
encountering a strange problem.

I cannot get the `show_bug.php` script  to work, even though the nearly identical
`show_product.php` script works like a charm.
When I try to use that `show_bug.php` script, no error message is given (even with
`ini_set(‘display_errors’, ‘On’);error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and no exception is thrown,
but "nothing" happens and the expected action is not taken.

With the help of my debugger, I was able to locate the problem more  precisely :
the compiler exits suddenly at line 211 of 
`vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php`

The content of this line is

```
require $fileName;
```

and the value of $fileName is `/var/folders/n2/_p480vgx4dx4rkk0prvbsbsr0000gn/T/__CG__User.php`,
a non-existent file on my system.

Here is the backtrace stack :

```
Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory->getProxyDefinition()
in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php

Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory->getProxy()
in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php

Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->createEntity()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php

Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\SimpleObjectHydrator->hydrateRowData()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php

Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\SimpleObjectHydrator->hydrateAllData()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php

Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator->hydrateAll()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php

Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->load()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php

{main}()
in show_bug.php
```

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE : As suggested in Martin's answer, I created a `Proxies` subdirectory in my project directory, and modified the contents of the `bootstrap.php` file as follows :

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$paths = array("src/");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname'   => 'flea_database',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$proxyDir='/Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Math_Software/Symfony_stuff/flee_tracker/Proxies';

$config -> setProxyDir($proxyDir); 

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

The behavior of the app did not change : show_product.php works but show_bug.php does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to generate the proxy files with the command line.

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:generate-proxies
```

This helped me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like it wasn't able to create Proxy classes (maybe your script didn't have rights to write to `/var/folders`). Have a look at [configuration](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager):

> Inside the Setup methods several assumptions are made:
>
> - ...
> - If third argument $proxyDir is not set, use the systems temporary directory.

Try setting `$proxyDir` to some temporary directory in your project and set write permissions to it.

Comment: Your suggestion turned out unhelpful, as I state in my update